# csvからint型のリストへ変換する方法

Tags: python, python3, csv

数値データが入ったcsvファイルがあります．形は2000行1列で各数値は改行で分けられています．
このcsvファイルを`[18231,1299,3001,...,2198]`のようにint型データのリストに変換したいです．
以下のコードを実行したのですが結果が思うような形にならないので，どなたか解決策を教えていただけませんか？　よろおしくお願いします．

```
with open('data.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = list(reader)
print(data)
```

> [['1128978'], ['117328'],..., ['24043']]

Comment: こちらが参考になるのでは？[Pythonで整数だけを含んだcsvを読み込む方法](https://qiita.com/Dsuke-K/items/de54eadbd970ac65e064)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

以下は `pandas.read_csv()` を使う方法です。

```py
# generate random numbers data
$ shuf -i 0-10000 -n 2000 > random_numbers.dat
$ head -5 random_numbers.dat 
8081
893
9727
2013
5957
$ wc -l random_numbers.dat 
2000 random_numbers.dat

# load from file
$ python3
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> lst = pd.read_csv('random_numbers.dat', header=None, dtype=int).iloc[:,0].tolist()
>>> len(lst)
2000
>>> lst
[8081, 893, 9727, 2013, 5957, ...
```

Answer (score 2):

こんな感じですかね。

```
import csv
import itertools
with open('data.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = [int(i) for i in list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(reader))]
print(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

色々な方法がありますが、素直にテキストとして読み取って数値化するサンプルコードの1つ目の方法がお勧めです。

csvは本質的に2次元配列なので、ご質問のコードを1次元配列に直す場合は4つ目の方法で内包表記を使って1次元配列化とint化しているような処理が必要です。

**data.csv**

```
データ
18231
1299
3001
2198
```

**サンプルコード**

```
# 1.テキストとして読み取って単純に数値化する
with open("data.csv") as f:
    # 数値化できるものだけ数値化
    data = [int(l) for l in f.read().splitlines() if l.isdecimal()]
    print(data)

# 2.csvを読み取って1列目を配列化する(ヘッダなし)
# cf: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46250109
import csv

data = []
with open('data.csv', newline='') as inputfile:
    for row in csv.reader(inputfile):
        if not row[0].isdecimal():   # 数値判定(不要なら削除)
            continue                 # 同上
        data.append(int(row[0]))

print(data)

# 3.csvを読み取って任意の列を配列化する(ヘッダあり)
import csv

data = []
with open('data.csv', newline='') as inputfile:
    for row in csv.DictReader(inputfile):
        data.append(int(row['データ']))

print(data)

# 4.多次元配列を1次元配列に変換する
import csv

with open('data.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    list = list(reader)
    del(list[0])          # ヘッダ行を取り除く(不要なら削除)
    data = [int(l[0]) for l in list]
    print(data)
```

**出力結果**

```
[18231, 1299, 3001, 2198]
[18231, 1299, 3001, 2198]
[18231, 1299, 3001, 2198]
[18231, 1299, 3001, 2198]
```